# A Bessel-like integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

I encounter the following integral when trying to find the inverse Fourier transform of the characteristic function of a certain sum of random variables. Here, $0\le\lambda\le1$, $p\ge0$, $q\ge0$ are real, and $n$ is an integer. I want to compute the following integral:

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} e^{p \cos (\lambda \tau) + q \cos ((1 - \lambda) \tau)}
\cos (n \tau) \frac{d \tau}{2 \pi}$$

This is a generalization of a Bessel integral, in that for $q = 0$ and $\lambda=1$, I know that:

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} e^{p \cos (\tau)}\cos (n \tau) \frac{d \tau}{2 \pi}
=I_n(p)$$

where $I_n(p)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind.